# How to specialize a non-templated-member function of a template class for multiple types?

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I'm biting of my nails on the syntax required to partially specialize a member function for multiple types. Here is what I have:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

class Property
{
public:
    virtual int read(uint8_t *) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class PropertyValue
{
    T value_;
public:
    int read(uint8_t *);
};

// specialized for std::string
template<>
int PropertyValue<std::string>::read(uint8_t *buf) { /* put string-value to buf */}
```

Now I would want to specialize the read-function for different enum-types. I tried a combination of `enable_if` and `is_same` which looks promissing, then putting it inside the template-declaration (compiler told me there are now 2 template arguments whereas 1 was expected).

Putting it inside the class-definition was not working either. Outside ... well, here's what I currently have.

```
// specialize for some enums
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, enum Enum1>::value ||
                        std::is_same<T, enum Enum2>::value, int>::type
PropertyValue<T>::read(uint8_t *buf)
{
    return encode_enum(buf, value_);
}
```

Where is my thinking wrong?

EDIT: Writing it like this compiles and works:

```
template<>
int PropertyValue<Enum 1>::read(uint8_t *buf)
{
    return encode_enum(buf, value_);
}

template<>
int PropertyValue<Enum 2>::read(uint8_t *buf)
{
    return encode_enum(buf, value_);
}
```

Comment: C++ doesn't allow you to define member functions of partial specializations like it does for full specializations. You need to define the partially specialized class first.

Comment: Please not that the `PropertyValue<std::string>::read(uint8_t *buf)` works fine (and others for basic types as well). Isn't that what is called partial specialization?

Comment: No `template<>` makes it a member of a full specialization. The "partial" comes from yet unspecified template parameters. It doesn't mean "part of a template".

Comment: OK, thanks, I thought the partial-specialization meant that part of a template-class is specialized explicitly by implementing part of it - explicitly and let the rest do the compiler

Comment: @StoryTeller I changed my title. I realize that the compiler is fully-specializing PropertyValue when I write `PropertyValue<Enum 1>` and associates the read-function.

Answer (score 3):

`PropertyValue::value` itself is not a template. It's not a template class, it's not a template function. It's a member of a template class, which is not the same thing as being a template itself.

You have to specialize the entire class.

```
template<>
class PropertyValue<std::string>
{
    std::string value_;
public:
    int read(uint8_t *)
    {
          // Your specialization goes here.
    }
};
```

Even if `read()` itself was a template, you must still specialize its class, before you can specialize a template class's template member.

Of course, if your template class has many other members and methods, every one of them have to be specialized here, leading to plenty of code getting duplicated. At that point, you will be faced with several options for refactoring out that duplicated code. The best approach for that depends on the particular details.

But that's how it's done...

EDIT: one common approach is to use a helper template class:

```
template<typename T> class PropertyValue; // Forward declaration

template<typename T> class do_read {
public:

    static int do_it( PropertyValue<T> &me, uint8_t *p )
    {
        // your default implementation
    }
};

template<> class do_read<std::string> {
public:

    static int do_it( PropertyValue<std::string> &me, uint8_t *p )
    {
        // your specialization
    }
};


template<typename T>
class PropertyValue
{
    T value_;
public:
    int read(uint8_t *p)
    {
          return do_read<T>::do_it(*this, p);
    }
};
```

Comment: I understand what you both (you and StoryTeller) are telling me, but the code (especially the read-function-specialization) above compiles and works, it is only the `enable_if/is_same`-part doesn't.

Comment: That's probably because when you try to invoke the specialized version, the default implementation also matches, leading to multiple methods matching your invocation. There's probably a way to make this work by using `std::enable_if_t` for both the default implementation and the specialization. But the end result won't be pretty. Anything but the most simple usage of `std::enable_if_t` usually makes my eyes bleed. Years later, when you go back to this code, you have to go get a paper and pencil to figure out how it works. Simple specializations are easier on my poor eyes.